# Can we say that iron on heating is a fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, metals, liquid-state

When iron is being put on fire, its forces with other atoms starts to break. We know a solid has more atoms and less spaces between them while liquids have more space as compared to solids (Also means less atoms than solids). Does that mean the atoms burn and remaining flow just like we have liquids.Therefore, solid on heating and until it is flowing or occupying space, it is a fluid.

Comment: Have you ever heard of molten iron?  What do you think that means?

Comment: Some liquids are denser than the solid at the melting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers you have received contain part of the story but are partially missing the main points beyond your questions: i) your starting point and ii) a correct intuitive picture of the liquid-solid transition based on an understanding of the phenomenon accordingly to contemporary physics.

**The starting point**

It contains a few misleading statements that could hamper a correct understanding of what a solid or a liquid is. When a solid melts, there is no real breaking of forces or bonds. The idea of bonds that are broken is a useless and dangerous idea borrowed from the different case of dissociation of molecules. In the case of a molecule, after dissociation, the fragments move away and we can safely speak about a bond that disappears. In a macroscopic piece of a solid, the melting transition does not change the interatomic distances too much. In some cases (for instance, water or silicon), the liquid phases' average distances are even smaller than in the solid. Moreover, a precise definition of a bond in condensed matter is not easy. However, some progress has been made in the last decades via a topological analysis of the electronic charge density. But the key point is that today there is no unambiguous and quantitative physical definition of bond that can shed light on the microscopic process of melting (and symmetrically, freezing).

In the previous paragraph, I have already mentioned that it is false that there is always less space between atoms in the solid. Often this is the case, but not always. No atom or molecule is appearing or disappearing in any case, whatever is the change of density at the solid-liquid transition. Different densities indeed give a different number of atoms *inside a fixed volume*, but this happens because due to the average expansion or contraction, a certain number of atoms crosses the fixed volume boundary. No one of them disappears or is burnt.

**A correct microscopic picture of the melting transition**

The different behavior of many observables characterizes crystalline solids and liquids. However, we should not forget that amorphous solids exist, blurring many possible characterizations of the transition based on the concept of spatial order or, on average *static* quantities. *Dynamical properties* remain a much clearer indication of the passage from a solid to a liquid phase. In particular, the apparently simple concept that liquid flow and solid don't is a good starting concept to build intuition on the melting process.

Here, I'll try to underline a few (correct) ideas one can connect to the fact that liquids flow.

1. Flowing implies a large relative displacement of far molecules; therefore, we have to expect a faster decaying with the distance of the correlation functions of a liquid.
2. Flowing also implies a large molecular movement even at smaller scales. Even in a hot solid, non-zero molecular diffusion is in place. However, in a solid, it is better described as a series of jumps well separated by time intervals where the motion is mainly vibrational.  Approaching the transition, this process becomes more continuous. The old-fashioned chemical idea of bond-breaking is substituted by an increased easiness for a local molecular motion continuously reshuffling the relative positions.
3. Notice that the previous point allows for understanding the solid-liquid transition in systems interacting via purely repulsive forces as a consequence of varying the pressure, like colloidal systems made by PMMA spheres. Purely repulsive interactions do not allow the introduction of a concept of *bond*. Instead, the local movement's dependence on the availability of available paths for a local diffusion can be used to provide a unified picture of the behaviors on melting.

Answer (score 4):

Even red-yellow hot, iron is solid enough. The work of a blacksmith is hammering heavily the stock to change little by little its shape.

The transition from solid to liquid is sudden, and once in the liquid phase, it's really a fluid and can easily fill cavities in foundry.

Some materials behave more in a intermediate state of solid-liquid, as glass for example. The craftsmans use that property to change its form through blowing into.

Answer (score 4):

> Does that mean the atoms burn ...

Atoms do not burn. Adding heat to a solid makes its atoms vibrate more energetically as their thermal energy increases. At a macroscopic level we would say that the temperature of the solid increases. This weakens the bonds between the atoms. Eventually the thermal energy of the atoms is sufficiently high for the interatomic bonds to break, and the solid melts and becomes a liquid (or, in some cases, transforms directly to its gas phase, which is called sublimation).

For a solid that has a regular and consistent atomic structure, like iron, the transition to its liquid phase takes place at a well defined temperature called its melting point. For a solid with an irregular atomic structure, such as glass, the transition from solid to liquid happens over a range of temperatures.

Comment: The word “burn” normally refers to either “the thing that fire does”, or certain _chemical_ reactions that occur when something gets hot – which should make it clear that an atom can't burn; chemical reactions are changes in how atoms are arranged, but apart from sometimes gaining or losing electrons nothing much really happens to the atoms themselves when this occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Heat is a shortened way of saying "heat energy." When something's hot, it has a lot of heat energy; when it's cold, it has less. But even things that seem cold (such as polar bears and icebergs) have rather more heat energy than you might suppose.